# Can't see Site Information in the menu on a new created SharePoint online Teamsite

Tags: sharepoint

When we create a site, that is both from SharePoint or the SharePoint admin center, the Site Information is not showing for users. The same even if the user is in the Owner group. I am sure it is a permission issue. However we cannot figure out where the problem is. It is very strange???

any suggestion will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, it may be related to the type of site you create. If the site you create is a classic experience site, it will not directly appear in the "All sites" view of Active sites. You need to switch "All sites" to "Classic sites". You will see the site, and then it will appear in the "All sites" view of the Active sites.

[image: where to change view]

For the site does not appear in SharePoint, it will appear in SharePoint only after the site is created and needs to have activities in it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback if there is any update. 

Please remember to update this thread if you have any progress. 

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Is there anything else I can help with regarding this issue? 
You can comment us at any time and we will continue to follow up.